# Dependency inversion in multi layer architecture

Tags: python, dependency-injection, fastapi, software-design

I've been learning about multi layer (onion) architecture when learning FastAPI. When I started practicing on real examples I faced some difficulties. Please look at the code below:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

from pydantic import BaseModel
from pymongo.collection import Collection
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session


class ProductDto(BaseModel):
    title: str
    weight: float


class IRepository(ABC):
    # interface for crud operations

    @abstractmethod
    def get(self, id_): pass

    @abstractmethod
    def create(self, create_data: dict): pass

    # another crud methods


class SqlRepository(IRepository):
    # implementation of crud methods in sql (sqlalchemy)

    model = None  # sqlalchemy model

    def __init__(self, session: Session):
        self._session = session

    def get(self, id_):
        print(f'getting instance id={id_} in SqlRepository')

    def create(self, create_data: dict):
        print(f'creating instance in SqlRepository')


class MongoRepository(IRepository):
    # implementation of crud methods with mongo

    def __init__(self, collection: Collection):
        self._collection = collection

    def get(self, id_):
        print(f'getting instance id={id_} in MongoRepository')

    def create(self, create_data: dict):
        print(f'creating instance in MongoRepository')


class IProductRepository(IRepository):
    # interface for product repository which will be use in type hints
    # method get_random_product was added to basic crud methods

    @abstractmethod
    def get_random_product(self): pass


class ProductSqlRepository(SqlRepository, IProductRepository):
    # sql implementation of ProductRepository interface
    def get_random_product(self):
        print('getting random product in ProductSqlRepository')


class ProductMongoRepository(MongoRepository, IProductRepository):
    # mongo implementation of ProductRepository interface
    def get_random_product(self):
        print('getting random product in ProductMongoRepository')


def process(repository: ProductRepository):
    repository.get(1)


sql_repo = ProductSqlRepository('session')
process(sql_repo)

mongo_repo = ProductMongoRepository('collection')
process(mongo_repo)
```

I'd like to provide the possibility of using different storages like sql, mongo, etc so I could just inject other repository.

Does it look ok? I doubt about this inheritance:

```
class ProductMongoRepository(MongoRepository, ProductRepository):
    def get_random_product(self):
        print('getting random product in ProductMongoRepository')
```

Please correct if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is valid, but I consider that in this case: "composition is better than inheritance" applies.
As you mention, this inheritance can be a bit confusing:

```
class ProductMongoRepository(MongoRepository, ProductRepository):
    def get_random_product(self):
        print('getting random product in ProductMongoRepository')
```

Then, I would prefer to do composition:

```
class ProductRepository(Repository):
    # interface for product repository which will be use in type hints
    # method get_random_product was added to basic crud methods

    @abstractmethod
    def get_random_product(self): pass


class ProductSqlRepository(ProductRepository):
    # sql implementation of ProductRepository interface
    def __init__(self, base_repository = SqlRepository("session")):
        self.base_repository = base_repository

    def get_random_product(self):
        print('getting random product in ProductSqlRepository')


class ProductMongoRepository(ProductRepository):
    # mongo implementation of ProductRepository interface
    def __init__(self, base_repository = MongoRepository("collection")):
        self.base_repository = base_repository

    def get_random_product(self):
        print('getting random product in ProductMongoRepository')


def process(repository: ProductRepository):
    repository.get(1)


sql_repo = ProductSqlRepository()
process(sql_repo)

mongo_repo = ProductMongoRepository()
process(mongo_repo)
```

You may need to adjust a couple of things, but in general the idea is that instead of inheriting you put an instance of the class as an attribute (dependency injection). Note that in this case we have injected an instance for what appear to be basic CRUD methods (in fact perhaps the interface could be called ICRUDRepository). But maybe then there is also another interface that you want to define for another group of related methods, you can easily inject that dependency as well.